# Vue template doesn't update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building my first project in VueJS, and I'm having trouble getting a template to show/hide using v-if. I have a data model boolean variable (groups.categories.descEditable) that I am toggling to show/hide a template. For some reason the template isn't reactively updating itself when I change that value.

```
<tbody v-for="group in groups">
    ...
    <tr v-for="cat in group.categories">
       ...
        <td class="td-indent">
            <input v-if="cat.descEditable" :value="cat.description" type="text" class="form-control">

            <div v-else v-on:click="editDesc(cat.id)">{{ cat.description }}</div>


            <div>{{cat.descEditable}}</div>
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>


methods: {
    editDesc (cat_id) {

        let vm = this

        this.groups.forEach(function(group, gr_ind){
            group.categories.forEach(function(cat, ind) {

                if (cat_id == cat.id)
                    cat.descEditable = true
                else 
                    cat.descEditable = false
            })
        })
    }
},
```

So I would like the text input to show if descEditable is true (once the div containing the description is clicked), otherwise show the div with the static description value. The descEditable property seems to be updating properly, but the v-if on the input element isn't reacting to it. I must be misunderstanding something fundamental to vuejs, just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I discovered that the template state actually IS updating internally, but its not rendering on the for some reason. I found a solution by calling vm.$forceUpdate(), but that seems like its not really the "right" answer. If someone has a better method please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can ditch the `editDesc` method entirely.

```js
console.clear()

const groups = [
  {
    categories:[
      {
        descEditable: false,
        description: "click me"
      
      }
    ]
  }
]


new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    groups
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody v-for="group in groups">
      <tr v-for="cat in group.categories">
        <td class="td-indent">
          <div v-if="cat.descEditable">
            <input v-model="cat.description" type="text" class="form-control">
            <button @click="cat.descEditable = false">Save</button>
         </div>
         <div v-else @click="cat.descEditable = true">{{ cat.description }}</div>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Points for elegance, but it still doesn't work. I discovered that the template state actually IS updating internally, but its not rendering on the for some reason. I can get it to render if I change the component file and then save, causing the Vue dev server to 'refresh' the dom. Obviously that doesn't solve my problem though.

Is there a way to force refresh Vue's DOM or some other "proper" way to ensure the changes get rendered?

Comment: @user3246127 This does work. There were a couple issues. I fabricated some data and converted it to a working example. In the future, please provide some data to work with or a working example demonstrating the problem. Makes things easier.

Comment: Odd that I can't get it to work for me (I'm using it inside a component if that matters). I'm able to get mine working by calling this.$forceUpdate(), but I like your solution better if only I could get it working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3246127 If you share the code I can take a look. Github, pastebin, whatever.

Comment: That would be great, full component here: https://gist.github.com/ChadTiffin/90ca1647ced97eb1efdccd3dd3961e01

Comment: @user3246127 Is `descEditable` a part of categories when you get it from the server or are you adding it in the computed?

Comment: I'm adding it the computed, it's not part of the server payload

Comment: @user3246127 When you add a property to an object, you need to do it via $set. That is likely your problem. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Here's a sample payload: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ChadTiffin/632bd2e54c15fad1234fbdc244584aa9/raw/38903ef78d9737d8bae9ea886efc574b905760e4/dummy%2520payload.json

Comment: $set was the problem! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3246127 You bet :)